# How to put information into a variable with Select function with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the select function to allow a user to choose a date from a list, and I don't know how to save his choice into a variable to use it afterwards in a loop.

Here is my select function:

```
<%= select( , , @benchmark.compositions.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.date_composition] }, :prompt => 'Selected date') %>
```

I want to save his choice (ex: date_selected = 2014-06-05) so I can make my object appear under the selected condition (date_compostion =  2014-06-05).

Comment: Do you want to save the select date value after submission of the form or on select/change?

Comment: On select/change would be nice, but after submission is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you set the name/id of the select element:

```
<%= select( 'resource', 'field', @benchmark.compositions.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.date_composition] }, :prompt => 'Selected date') %>
```

That will generate an HTML that will look like:

```
<select id="resource_field" name="resource[field]">
<option ..... /option>
</select>
```

Then If you want to get the value on select/change you can do it via Coffeescript or JQuery. Ex:

```
# coffeescript which is located under app/assets/javascripts/__a_controller_name__.js.coffee
$(document).ready =>·
  $('#resource_field').change ->
    alert( $(this).val() )
```

The select element is `$('#resource_field')`.

If you want to get the value after submission, you can get the value from the controller by accessing the 'params' variable:

```
# a method under a controller
def sample_method
  @resource_field = params[:resource][:field]
end
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be what I need. But can I ask you to be more specific about the first solution ? I installed the Coffeescript gem, put it in my Gemfile, created a file named benchmarks_controller.js.coffee in the folder you mentioned. But when the user chooses a date on the application, it doesn't seem to change anything and when I use $('#resource_field') in my code, it says "syntax error"